# Chamar um método estático pelo nome como string no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, static

Se eu quiser chamar uma função estática pelo nome como string, como faço?

Eu fiz o que está abaixo, suponha que o nome da função é "move".

```
class Transformation {
    static operate(object, function_name) {
          eval(function_name)(object);
    }
    static move(object) {... some code...}
}
```

Mas não funcionou.

OBS: Eu estou chamando essa função de um outro arquivo no mesmo diretório.

Comment: Traduzi a pergunta para o português. Mas fica o aviso: normalmente as perguntas que são postadas em inglês neste site são rapidamente fechadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito o que você quer, mas talvez seja isso:

```js
class Transformation {
    static operate(function_name, object) {
        Transformation[function_name](object);
    }
    static move(object) { alert("oi " + object); }
}

Transformation.operate("move", "teste");
```